# Meteor Accounts Not Displaying Input Fields

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

Im working on Meteor Accounts. I have routes and the AccountsTemplate configured, but when I am on the route page, the input fields are not displaying.

Here is my AccountsTemplate configurations:

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
  defaultTemplate: 'atForm',
  defaultLayout: 'Appbody',
  defaultContentRegion: 'main',
  showForgotPasswordLink: true,
  enablePasswordChange: true,
 sendVerificationEmail: true,
 confirmPassword: true,
 forbidClientAccountCreation: false,
 showPlaceholders: true,
 continuousValidation: true,
 negativeValidation: true,
  defaultLayoutRegions: {},
  texts: {
      button: {
          signUp: "Register Now!",
      }
    }
});

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn', {
  name: 'signin',
  path: '/signin'
});

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signUp', {
  name: 'join',
  path: '/join'
});

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('forgotPwd');

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('resetPwd', {
  name: 'resetPwd',
  path: '/reset-password'
});
```

However, when viewing in the browser, the input fields are hidden, for both sign-in and register pages. Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have accounts UI and accounts password installed?

Comment: No I do not have them installed.

Comment: I do have unstyled installed...is that wrong?

Comment: Are you already logged in to your application ? I had a similar problem, and I was already logged in to my application and those fields were not visible to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you download the accounts:core package with accounts:unstyled, you also need to install accounts:password (or the fields will not show up)